# How to transform an initial table containing codes to its corresponding description

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table which contains only identifier codes:

| importer | exporter | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1001 |
| 2 | 1 | 1002 |
| 3 | 2 | 1003 |

*in the actual database the importer, exporter, and product has a variable of j, i, and k respectively*

The single digit codes were country codes, whereas the four digit codes refer to the product that these countries bought.

| country_code | country_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | USA |
| 2 | Canada |
| 3 | UK |

| product_code | product_description |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | agriculture |
| 1002 | petroleum |
| 1003 | electronics |

I wanted to transform the initial table from only containing codes to becoming table that contains all of the details that these codes are referring to.

| importer | exporter | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | UK | agriculture |
| Canada | USA | petroleum |
| UK | Canada | electronics |

I have tried the following in BigQuery

```
SELECT
  country.country_name_full AS buyer,
  product.description AS product_description,
  country.country_name_full AS seller
FROM
  `my-first-data-project-365122.cepii_export.country_codes` AS country
RIGHT JOIN
  `my-first-data-project-365122.cepii_export.Trade_Flow` AS raw_data
  ON  country.country_code = raw_data.j
RIGHT JOIN
  `my-first-data-project-365122.cepii_export.product_codes` AS product
  ON product.code = raw_data.k
RIGHT JOIN
  ON country.country_code = raw_data.i
```

I managed to get the first two rows (importer and product) to display correctly but when I tried to duplicate the join statement for the 'exporter' the program keep throwing me an error saying that the ON statement were unexpected

Comment: you are missing table reference after last JOIN! just add it and you are good

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT Importer.country_name_full AS buyer,
   Exporter.country_name_full AS seller, 
   product.description AS product_description 
   FROM raw_data 
   LEFT JOIN Country_codes AS Importer ON Importer.country_code = 
   raw_data.j 
   LEFT JOIN Country_code AS Exporter ON Exporter.country_code = 
   raw_data.i LEFT JOIN Product_codes AS product ON product.code = raw_data.k
```